When using dask dataframe, temporary files seem to accumulate
I aggregate data using outer join and groupby.sum with a dask dataframe, but the size of the temporary file becomes too large compared to the data.
My data size is about 50GB, but when I worked on 1/10th of it, it was about 750GB.
The code reads data from 5 folders, readjusts the columns of 4 folders, and performs an outer join with the remaining folders. Then, after counting, it is exported to a csv file.
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

def rpt_dask_dataframe(folder_path, using_cols=None):
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.rpt"))

    # Check if the folder is empty
    if len(all_files) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No files found in the folder")
    # Check file header row to get the column names.
    # the header start with '!' or '&' the last one is the header row
    header_row = None
    for file in all_files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('!') or line.startswith('&'):
                    header_row = line
                    break
        if header_row is not None:
            break

    if using_cols is None:
        dask_df = dd.read_csv(all_files)
    else:
        dask_df = dd.read_csv(all_files, usecols=using_cols)
    return dask_df

def unique_list(l):
    x = []
    for a in l:
        if a not in x:
            x.append(a)
    return x


folder_path = r'C:/Users/USER/Desktop'

folder_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

folder_dict = {'BF_EB': 1, 'BF_NB1': 2, 'BF_NB2': 3, 'BF_NB3': 4, 'AF_EB': 5}

folder_list = [os.path.join(folder_path, folder) for folder in folder_list if folder in     folder_dict]

result_folder = r'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/result'

if not os.path.exists(result_folder):
    os.makedirs(result_folder)

reference_folder = r'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/ref_info.fac'

reference_df = dd.read_csv(reference_folder, usecols=[1, 2], dtype=str)

reference_df = reference_df.compute()

pk_list = ['pk1', 'pk2', 'pk3', 'pk4', 'pk5', 'pk6', 'pk7', 'pk8']
fk_list = ['fk1', 'fk2']
value1_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
value2_list = ['value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8']
main_list = pk_list + fk_list + value1_list

result_col_list = ['ref1', 'pk1', 'pk2', 'pk3', 'pk4', 'fk1', 'fk2', 'value4', 'value4_BF',     'value4_AF', 'Cvalue1_BF', 'Cvalue1_AF',
                   'value3_BF', 'value5', 'value5_BF', 'value5_AF', 'value6', 'value6_BF',     'value6_AF', 'value6_DEL', 'value6_ADD',
                   'value7_BF', 'value7_AF', 'value8_BF', 'value8_AF', 'value9_BF',     'value9_AF', 'value10_BF', 'value10_AF']

summary_columns = ['rsf1', 'pk1', 'pk2', 'pk3', 'fk1', 'fk2']
summary_key_num = len(summary_columns)

#usecols & rename
df_BF_EB = rpt_dask_dataframe(folder_list[0], unique_list(main_list + [_ + ' M3' for _ in     value2_list])).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace("_M3", "_BF"))
df_BF_NB1 = rpt_dask_dataframe(folder_list[1], unique_list(main_list + [_ + 'M3' for _ in     value2_list])).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('M3', '_BF'))
df_BF_NB2 = rpt_dask_dataframe(folder_list[2], unique_list(main_list + [_ + ' M2' for _ in     value2_list])).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace("M2", '_BF'))
df_BF_NB3 = rpt_dask_dataframe(folder_list[3], unique_list(main_list + [_ + '_M1' for _ in     value2_list])).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_M1', '_BF'))
df_AF_EB = rpt_dask_dataframe(folder_list[4], unique_list(main_list +     value2_list)).rename(columns=lambda x: x + '_AF' if x in value2_list else x)

df_BF = dd.concat([df_BF_EB, df_BF_NB1, df_BF_NB2, df_BF_NB3], axis=0)

joined_df = dd.merge(df_BF, df_AF_EB, how='outer', on=pk_list, suffixes=['_BF', '_AF'])

# Apply vectorized operations instead of row-wise apply
joined_df['fk1'] = joined_df['fk1_AF'].combine_first(joined_df['fk1_BF'])
joined_df['fk2'] = joined_df['fk2_AF'].combine_first(joined_df['fk2_BF'])
joined_df['Cvalue1_BF'] = joined_df['value1_BF'] + joined_df['value2_BF']
joined_df['Cvalue1_AF'] = joined_df['value1_AF'] + joined_df['value2_AF']
joined_df['value6_DEL'] = joined_df['value6_BF'].where(joined_df['value6_AF'].isna(), 0)
joined_df['value6_ADD'] = joined_df['value6_AF'].where(joined_df['value6_BF'].isna(), 0)
joined_df = joined_df.drop(columns=['fk1_AF', 'fk1_BF', 'fk2_AF', 'fk2_BF', 'value1_AF',     'value1_BF', 'value2_AF', 'value2_BF'])

joined_df = dd.merge(joined_df, reference_df, how='left', on='pk4')

joined_df = joined_df.loc[:, result_col_list]

# Persist joined_df to disk
joined_df = joined_df.persist()

# Convert to delayed and delete joined_df
df_enum = enumerate(joined_df.to_delayed())
del joined_df

for i, chunk in df_enum:
    result = chunk.groupby(summary_columns).sum().compute()    
    result.to_csv(os.path.join(result_folder, f'result_{i}.csv'), index=True)    
    del chunk
    del result


agg_data = dd.read_csv(os.path.join(result_folder, 'result_*.csv'))
agg_data = agg_data.groupby(summary_columns).sum().compute()
agg_data.to_csv(os.path.join(result_folder, 'result.csv'), index=True)


Hi, your code is not reproducible and very complicated. You should work step by step. I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve with the merge part, and persit persists in memory, not to disk. You should try to work with a much simpler problem first that reproduces your error.

There are some helpful guidelines on simplifying your code to isolate the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
